# Send data to serial port in little endian

Tags: matlab, serial-port, endianness, fwrite

I am trying to send some floating-point data to a serial port. The data by default is getting transmitted in big-endian. I am using the following code:

```
ser = serial('COM1');
set(ser,'BaudRate',115200);
fopen(ser);
fwrite(ser,1.7,'single'); %sends in big-endian format
```

Matlab documentation for `fwrite` does mention the format:

```
fwrite(fileID,A,precision,skip,machinefmt)
```

where machinefmt can change endianness but that does not seem to work while writing to serial port.

```
fwrite(ser,1.7,'single',0,'ieee-le');
fwrite(ser,1.7,'single',0,'l');
```

Both these commands throw the error:

> Error using serial/fwrite (line 124)
>
> Too many input arguments.

Is there a workaround for sending data in little-endian format?

Comment: The answer from @MarcosG is correct, `little-endian` is the default option for the MATLAB serial port. What makes you say that the data is transmitted in a big endian format ?

Comment: oh ok. I mixed up big endianness with little endianness because I was receiving in the reverse order on my target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have read the documentation for writing to a file.

In recent versions of Matlab at least `fwrite` has its own help and if you read it you'll see that the endianness is a property.

First, create the port:

```
ser = serial('COM1');
```

And then check or change its endianness:

```
get(ser,'ByteOrder')
set(ser,'ByteOrder', 'littleEndian')
```

By the way, I think the default option is little-endian, so you might want to try `bigEndian`.

Source: [Matlab help](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/getting-started-with-serial-i-o.html#f61191)